# Run time error in simple program to print all elements of the array

Tags: java, arrays

Question: Given an array, print all its elements. First line of input contains number of test cases. The output should be as follows:-

[image: snapshot of example output..how it should be like]

What is wrong in the following code?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t= sc.nextInt();

        int arr[][] = new int[t][];
        int len[] = new int[t];

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            len[i]= sc.nextInt();
            arr[i] = new int[len[i]];

            for(int j=0;j<len[i];j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]) );
            for(int j=0;i<len[i];j++)
            {
                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at GFG.main(GFG.java:24)
```

Comment: What is the exception you are facing ?

Comment: question is not clear, what you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

As printed on exception

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>   at GFG.main(GFG.java:24)

on line 23 replace i with j because loop continues because of i

```
class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();

        int arr[][] = new int[t][];
        int len[] = new int[t];

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            len[i] = sc.nextInt();
            arr[i] = new int[len[i]];

            for (int j = 0; j < len[i]; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]) );
            for (int j = 0; j < len[i]; j++) {  // replaced i with j I think  copy paste problem
                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception is in line

```
for(int j=0;i<len[i];j++)
```

you are incrementing `j` without having any boundary,hence it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception. It will print till 5 that is `1 2 3 4 5` but after that it will give `runtime` exception.

Change to

```
for(int j=0;j<len[i];j++)
```